# css 100 height with borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a card list in using html/css/javascript.
Here are the two sample implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/235Tp/

```
#wrapper {
    background: #EEE;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#cards-div {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

#cards-list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#cards-list li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: #EEE;
    margin-left: -14%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#cards-list li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scctk/

You can see that one has borders while another has not.
The one with borders has a y-asix scrolling bar that I do not want to include.
How to remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` (and `-moz-box-sizing`) to have the border included in the width/height calculation of the box model.

http://jsfiddle.net/235Tp/3/

Answer (score 2):

Just simply change `overflow-y:auto` to `overflow-y:hidden;` as shown:

```
#cards-div {
background: green;
width: 100%;
height: 70%;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

}

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/235Tp/4/)

Comment: I know about this. But do you recognise that the bottom border disappeared?